# API data In VueJS

Tags: vue.js, get

I'm trying to show email conversation data in vuejs. Somehow It's not rendering on the page. I fetch the conversation on the pages but can't show it properly like an email thread. Here is my code below. can someone help me?

```
<template>
<div v-for="item in messages" v-bind:key="item" class="post">
         
     {{messages.conversationHistory}}
         
      </div>
 
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  
  
  export default {
      name: 'consume-rest-api',
      data(){
          return{
              messages: null,
              
          }
      },
  
      created() {
          axios.get(`http://sa-test-task-2022.s3-website.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/messages`)
              .then(response => {
                  // JSON responses are automatically parsed.
                  this.messages = response.data
              })
              .catch(e => {
                  this.errors.push(e)
              });
      }
  }
  </script>
  
  <style scoped>
  </style>
```

Comment: you mean you're getting a completely blank page?  are there any errors in your browser's dev console?

Comment: i'm completely getting blank page and no error in consolelog

Comment: weird.  when I run your code I get errors immediately.  1) the `<div v-for>` is going to produce multiple sibling `div` elements which is an error because there can be only one root element in your template.  so first correction is to surround your template code with another `<div></div>`

Comment: second issue is you're assigning an object `item` as the `:key` property.  Keys should always be either a string or number.  looking at the data you're fetching, `v-bind:key="item.messageId"` would be a more appropriate key.  After fixing these two issues with your code I get a large amount of JSON data printed to the screen.

Comment: <template>
  <div v-for="item in messages" v-bind:key="item.messageId" class="post">
           
       
           
        </div>
   
    </template>

Comment: what should goes in my div then to show the email thread that I'm fetching.

Comment: I'm trying to show conversation history object in my page.

Comment: what you had inside of the div was fine.  I was trying to say for the first issue your div with the `v-for` needs to be wrapped in another `div`.  I will post an answer with a code snippet so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. wrap the `v-for` in another div because you can only have 1 root element (the `v-for` will end up generating multiple sibling divs)
2. objects should not be used as `:key` values.  use a string or number, e.g. `:key="item.messageId"`

Fixed template code:

```html
<template>
  <div> 
    <div v-for="item in messages" v-bind:key="item.messageId" class="post">
      {{ messages.conversationHistory }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

If you only want to print the first conversation (the `v-if` ensures the conversationHistory exists before trying to render):

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="messages?.conversationHistory">
    {{ messages.conversationHistory[0] }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: now I'm getting 10 of {{ messages.conversationHistory }} object.  like 10 of subject, 10 attachments 10 of cc etc etc . I just need one object. How can I only show one object ?

Comment: `messages.conversationHistory` is an array of conversation items.  they are not duplicates. they each represent a different conversation.  the `v-for` loops through the given array and prints each one.  if you want to only print one, it depends on which one... but I will add to my answer showing how you would print only the first conversation

Comment: how can I style them , like a class for action,class for subject and for other properties?

Comment: if you want to get just the subject you would print it like this inside the div: `{{ messages.conversationHistory[0].subject }}`.  you can access each property in a similar way.  put each property in a different `div` or other element, give them classes, then bind the classes to certain styles.

Comment: no problem.  if your issue is resolved please consider upvoting and marking the answer as correct.  thank you!